# Converting List<string> to byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, generics, c#-4.0

How can I take a List and turn it into a byte array.

I thought there might be some clever LINQ options for it but am unsure eg/List.ForEach

Comment: Whats wrong with a simple for loop?

Comment: 1 byte[] for each string on the list or a single byte[] that containts all the strings on the list.?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Depends on which encoding you want to use to convert the `string` to a `byte[]` but here's a sample for ASCII.  It can be substituted for pretty much any encoding type

```
List<string> data = ...
byte[] dataAsBytes = data
  .SelectMany(s => Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s))
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: if you want new line for each item use `.GetBytes(s + Environment.NewLine))`

Answer (score 0):

with a simple foreach loop:

(pseudocode)

```
    List<byte[]> bytes = new List<byte[]>();
    ForEach string el in somelist
        {
           byte[] arr;
           System.Text.UTF8Encoding  encoding=new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
           arr = encoding.GetBytes(el);
           bytes.add(arr);
        }
```

Comment: That will give you a `List<byte[]>` but the OP asked for a `byte[]`